# meteorjs okgrow:analytics - working only on localhost

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement  [`okgrow:analytics`](https://github.com/okgrow/analytics) to my meteorjs application, but
it works only on local machine. When I deploy an application on heroku, it do not fire any log events.

I have everything set up according the tutorial and cannot find the problem. Unfortunately, there is not any error event to anchor to.

My settings.json is

```
    {
      "AWSAccessKeyId" : "***",
      "AWSSecretAccessKey" : "***",
      "AWSBucket" : "recallmagic",
      "public": {
        "analyticsSettings": {
          "Google Analytics" : {"trackingId": "UA-***"},     
          "Mixpanel"         : {"token":  "***", "people": true}
        }
      }
    }
```

I am calling track function :

```
    analytics.track("Bought Ticket", {
      eventName: "Wine Tasting",
      couponValue: 50,
    });
```

It renders GA and Mixpanel js code properly on localhost, but this is not
the case after pushing on heroku.

I am using [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi)

with the .buildpacks file containing

```
    https://github.com/rocketmobile/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick.git
    https://github.com/seviu/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git
```

Are there any specialities to do when deploying `okgrow:analytics` on heroku?

Comment: You can use ` around words to format them as code if you want to refer to names.

Comment: thanks, I created proper reference to the github repo of the okgrow:analytics package

Comment: It would also be worth expanding on the problems you see; for example, are there any logs on heroku that suggests whether it is being installed? It's difficult to offer advice if there's no specific data.

Comment: thank you for help. I tried to put as much info as possible now

Comment: That's a lot more detailed, even if you couldn't find any error. I'm not a Heroku person so can't answer but your question stands a better chance of being answered now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was, that I did not have config updated on heroku

heroku config:add METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json)"